# Problem with icon color in .NET Windows Forms menu

Tags: .net, winforms, image, colors, menuitem

I'm using VS2008 and I'm creating a Windows Forms project. The form has a menu of MenuStrip class, and the items are (surprise, surprise) ToolStripMenuItem objects.

I want to add pretty icons from the [FamFamFam Silk](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) icon set. All is nice and fine, until I got to the "copy" icon. You can see it [here](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/previews/index_abc.png) (warning! 1MB image!) under the name "page_white_copy". What I get is far from the image I'd expect.

Any ideas why the colors are all messed up?

**Added:** Here's an image that shows what I mean:

http://valts.21.lv/problem/MenuColor.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! Found it!

The MenuItem's TransparentColor was set to black, so it made the outline of the image disappear (which was black with about 50% transparency)!

Answer (score 0):

How'd you get the image into the project? I'm guessing it has to do with some color being misinterpreted as an alpha channel. I'd save the icon you want as a .PNG to see if that fixes it.

Comment: The icon was a PNG to begin with. And I even changed it from 8-bit grayscale to full 32-bit image - but no luck. I even tried deleting any non-important chunks leaving just the data because some MS products (like IE) have gamma issues. But nop. The weird thing is - the image when imported in the forms resource is getting messed up. But even if I modify the resource file "by hand" and fix it, it does not help.

Comment: I tried exporting the messed up version and comparing it to the correct version - seems that the alpha channel for the outline of the icons is reset. But some other pixels have their alpha channels correct. Weird...